# Error socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a website with a real time chat it works on localhost without error but on server I get this error.

`https://app.webku.org:8181/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MZpzI2p
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

this is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8181);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('new_chats', function(data){
    io.emit('new_chats', { ua: data.ua, message: data.message });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('State disconnected');
  });
});
```

and this is on client side

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
        var socket = io.connect('https://app.webku.org:8181');

        $(document).on('keypress', function(e){
           var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
           var msg = 'testing message';
           if( key == 13 ){
              socket.emit('new_chats', { ua: <%= user[0].user_id %>, message: msg });
           }
        });

    socket.on('new_chats', function(data){
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.getHours() +':'+ d.getMinutes();

            var tpos = 'text-left';
            if(data.ua == <%= user[0].user_id %>){ tpos = 'text-right'; }

            $('#_icard'+ua).find('.ibody ul').append(
              '<li class="'+tpos+'">' +
                '<div> '+data.message+' <small class="small">'+t+'</small> </div>' +
              '</li>'
            );

          });
</script>
```

How I can solve this problem? thank you so much.

Comment: Since your code works fine for localhost but not for a certain URL you should start debugging the URL. Start with making sure the domain name is reachable, the port is bound to the ip address and reachable, the path (which might be the same for local  host). Start by setting the host to 0.0.0.0 and then work your way towards firewalls, iptables. Just a few pointers.

Comment: Additionally add error handling on the client side and print error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running a HTTP server on your server.

However in your client script you are trying to connect using HTTPS to your server.

Try running a HTTPS server or if you are okay with HTTP change your client code to connect through HTTP.